# Observe implicit size changes on HTMLElements

Tags: javascript, mutation-observers

While the MutationObserver allows monitoring explicit size changes to an HTMLElement's attribute, it doesn't seem to have a way/config that allow me to monitor *implicit* changes to it's size, which are computed by the browser.

Here's an example:

```js
const observer = new MutationObserver(changes => {
  console.log('changed')
})

observer.observe(document.querySelector('#bar'), {
  attributes: true
})

document.querySelector('#foo').style.width = '200px'
```

```css
.container {
  display: flex;
  align-items: stretch;
}

.child {
  width: 100px;
  height: 100px;
  margin: 0 2px;
  background: magenta;
}
```

```html
<div class="container">
  <div class="child" id="foo"></div>
  <div class="child" id="bar"></div>
</div>
```

In the above example I'm changing the size of `#foo`, while observing `#bar`. `#bar` get's squished by `#foo` (it's width changes implicitly, since the browser computed it's width instead of me explicitly specifying it).

How can I detect such implicit size changes?

Comment: https://wicg.github.io/ResizeObserver/

Answer (score 3, accepted):

*...However, resize events are only fired on (sent to) the window object* :: [MDN](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/Events/resize)

New standard is :: [Resize Observer](https://wicg.github.io/ResizeObserver/)

```
new ResizeObserver(()=>console.log('bar dimension changed :: RO!')).observe(bar);
```

But while it's for late Chrome only I suggest some library, like:
[CSS-Element-Queries](http://marcj.github.io/css-element-queries/)

```
<script src="css-element-queries-1.0.0/src/ResizeSensor.js"></script>
<script src="css-element-queries-1.0.0/src/ElementQueries.js"></script>
new ResizeSensor(bar, function(){ 
    console.log('bar dimension changed :: CSS-Element-Queries');
});
```

Comment: I'm worried that ResizeSensor and/or ElementQueries will use polling to figure out if it changed or not, which will be detrimental to performance. Do you have any idea what approach they use to determine changes?

Comment: Both are event based.

Comment: Which event fires on element resize? If it did wouldn't I be able to pick it up myself w/o using libraries?

Comment: ResizeObserver is browsers inner tech. Available from Chrome 64(?). Css-Element-Query is using requestAnimationFrame and iterating whole DOM tree

Answer (score -2):

```html
Hi just take the javascript part to the end of the body

<!DOCTYPE HTML>
<html>
<head>
    <style>
        .container {
            display: flex;
            align-items: stretch;
            
        }

        .child {
            width: 200px;
            height: 100px;
            margin: 0 2px;
            background: magenta;
        }
       
    </style>
   
</head>

<body onload="">

    <div class="container">
        <div class="child" id="foo"></div>
        <div class="child" id="bar"></div>
    </div>
    <script>
        const observer = new MutationObserver(changes => {
            console.log('changed')
        });

        observer.observe(document.querySelector('#bar'), {
            attributes: true
        });

        document.querySelector('#foo').style.width = '400px'
    </script>
</body>
</html>
```

Comment: I don't think you understood what my question is all about.

Comment: according to observing #bar. #bar get's squished by #foo I change anyway

Comment: Sorry, no. Your answer is completely wrong. This has nothing to do with script loading issues. Also in your supposedly "fixed" example the callback doesn't fire.